# Elegant way to change legend's title size in seaborn plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a seaborn pairplot and I want to change the size of the legend's title. 
I have done that with:

```
matrix = sns.pairplot(...)
lg = plt.gcf().legend(title='something')
lg.get_title().set_fontsize(30)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I know that matplotlib -used by seaborn- does not have a related property as discussed here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8699

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that [from matplotlib 3.0 on](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10715), you will be able to change the legend title font-size via

```
ax.legend(..., title_fontsize=16)
```

or

```
plt.rcParams['title_fontsize'] = 16
```

Until then,

```
legend = ax.legend(...)
legend.get_title().set_fontsize(16)
```

is indeed the appropriate way to set the legend title.

Comment: ok nice, at least its good to know that there is still no better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

To change the plot legend's title font size

`plt.title('something', fontsize=16)`

Comment: This does not change the legend's title fontsize, not sure why it was accepted?